# Why my SSE code is slower than native C++ code?

Tags: c++, sse, simd

First of all, I am new to SSE. I decided to accelerate my code, but it seems, that it works slower, then my native code.

This is an example, that calculates the sum of squares. On my Intel i7-6700HQ, it takes 0.43s for native code and 0.52 for SSE. So, where is a bottleneck?

```
inline float squared_sum(const float x, const float y)
{
    return x * x + y * y;
}

#define USE_SIMD

void calculations()
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;

    int result_v = 0;

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    alignas(16) float data_x[4];
    alignas(16) float data_y[4];
    alignas(16) float result[4];
    __m128 v_x, v_y, v_res;
    for (int y = 0; y < 5120; y++)
    {
        data_y[0] = y;
        data_y[1] = y + 1;
        data_y[2] = y + 2;
        data_y[3] = y + 3;
        for (int x = 0; x < 5120; x++)
        {
            data_x[0] = x;
            data_x[1] = x + 1;
            data_x[2] = x + 2;
            data_x[3] = x + 3;
#ifdef USE_SIMD
            v_x = _mm_load_ps(data_x);
            v_y = _mm_load_ps(data_y);
            v_x = _mm_mul_ps(v_x, v_x);
            v_y = _mm_mul_ps(v_y, v_y);
            v_res = _mm_add_ps(v_x, v_y);
            _mm_store_ps(result, v_res);
#else
            result[0] = squared_sum(data_x[0], data_y[0]);
            result[1] = squared_sum(data_x[1], data_y[1]);
            result[2] = squared_sum(data_x[2], data_y[2]);
            result[3] = squared_sum(data_x[3], data_y[3]);
#endif

            result_v += (int)(result[0] + result[1] + result[2] + result[3]);
        }
    }

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<double> time_span1 = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "Exec time:\t" << time_span1.count() << " s\n";
}
```

## **UPDATE: fixed code according to comments.**

I am using Visual Studio 2017. Compiled for x64.

- Optimization: **Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)**;
- Inline Function Expansion: **Any Suitable (/Ob2)**;
- Favor Size or Speed: **Favor fast code (/Ot)**;
- Omit Frame Pointers: **Yes (/Oy)**

## Conclusion

Compilers generate already optimized code, so nowadays it is hard to accelerate it even more. The one thing you can do, to accelerate code more, is parallelization.

Thanks for the answers. They mainly the same, so I accept Søren V. Poulsen answer because it was the first.

Comment: how did you compile? Optimizations turned on?

Comment: The compiler [is already using SIMD](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_8yZN1). (In the future, please make your code ready to copy/paste. This means fixing types like `tbb` instead of `std` and `##endif` instead of `#endif`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: I would speculate that `tbb` is a namespace used by Intel "Threading Building Blocks" and not a mistyped `std`.

Comment: @OP The calculation of `v_y` can and should be lifted out of the inner loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. OP provided an incomplete code fragment, and I had to wrestle it into submission.

Comment: What compiler, version? Did you check the generated assembly?

Comment: @user463035818 Updated a question.

Comment: @RaymondChen Code updated (sorry for that). So it is impossible to accelerate code more?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's going to be very hard. One way to do it is to optimize the algorithm rather than trying to optimize the algorithm's steps. For example, the `result` vector is always `{ x*x + y+y, (x+1)*(x+1) + (y+1)*(y+1), (x+2)*(x+2) + (y+2)*(y+2), (x+3)*(x+3)+(y+3)*(y+3) }`. The `y` part doesn't change in the loop so you don't have to keep calculating it, and the `x` part can be strength-reduced. And actually, the result is always the same, so you can just precalculate the whole thing and set `result_v` to the final answer and never run the loops at all.

Comment: Assuming exact math (no rounding errors), it is really not very hard to find an explicit formula for what you are calculating, e.g., using [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(x%3D0)%5EN+sum_(y%3D0)%5EM+sum_(k%3D0)%5E3+((x%2Bk)%5E2%2B(y%2Bk)%5E2)). But actually, you are not even using the result, so you can completly avoid doing any calculation at all.

Comment: @RaymondChen OK, this is not my actual algorithm, but a part of it. Actually, the real part is a sum of squares. And rest part is for the performance test.

Comment: @chtz As I mentioned above this code is only for performance tests.

Comment: @user1554270 Make sure that your performance test actually resembles your actual use case. It makes a significant difference if you generate data on the fly or read it from memory. Also, compilers are sometimes smart enough to evaluate entire loops at compile time (especially if you would have used integer everywhere).

Comment: It looks like the part that's destroying performance for your manual vectorization is a naive scalar horizontal sum *inside* the inner loop.  Your manual vectorization is as good as what a compiler can do (unless it uses FMA instructions, like if you compiler with `-O3 -march=native`, but some compilers, like gcc, will collapse mul+add intrinsics into FMA). Anyway, summing into an FP vector that you convert to integer and hsum at the end would be much better. (But not equivalent because it matters where you round; I think your code unavoidably costs lots of work unless optimized away.)

Comment: @PeterCordes clang also collapses mul+add into FMA, but only if you enable (at least a subset of) `-ffast-math`: https://godbolt.org/z/C7IFfJ which, IMO, makes sense, since it will actually alter the result of floating point math.

Comment: @chtz: right, but GCC contracts (that's the right technical term, not collapse, oops) to FMA even without `-ffast-math`.  That's legal *within* one expression in ISO C (and I assume C++), but not strictly legal across expressions (like nested intrinsics or assignment to a tmp variable in a separate statement.)  [How to use Fused Multiply-Add (FMA) instructions with SSE/AVX](//stackoverflow.com/a/15933677).  Compilers are allowed to have `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON` on by default.  But GCC is still bending the rules here.  It's usually a good, thing, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern compiles are incredible machines and will already use SIMD instructions if possible (and with the correct compilation flags).

One general strategy to determine what the compiler is doing is looking at the disassembly of your code. If you don't want to do it on your own machine you can use an online service like Godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T6GooQ.

One tip is to avoid `atomic` for storing intermediate results like you are doing here. Atomic values are used to ensure synchronization between threads, and this may come at a very high computational cost, relatively speaking.

Comment: OK. atomic is left from multithreaded optimization. Removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the assembly for the compiler's code based (without your SIMD stuff),

```
calculations():
        pxor    xmm2, xmm2
        xor     edx, edx
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movdqa  xmm11, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movdqa  xmm9, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        movdqa  xmm8, XMMWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
        movdqa  xmm7, XMMWORD PTR .LC4[rip]
.L4:
        movdqa  xmm5, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm4, xmm0
        cvtdq2ps        xmm6, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm10, xmm0
        paddd   xmm0, xmm7
        cvtdq2ps        xmm3, xmm0
        paddd   xmm5, xmm9
        paddd   xmm4, xmm8
        cvtdq2ps        xmm5, xmm5
        cvtdq2ps        xmm4, xmm4
        mulps   xmm6, xmm6
        mov     eax, 5120
        paddd   xmm10, xmm11
        mulps   xmm5, xmm5
        mulps   xmm4, xmm4
        mulps   xmm3, xmm3
        pxor    xmm12, xmm12
.L2:
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm12
        cvtdq2ps        xmm14, xmm12
        mulps   xmm14, xmm14
        movdqa  xmm13, xmm12
        paddd   xmm12, xmm7
        cvtdq2ps        xmm12, xmm12
        paddd   xmm1, xmm9
        cvtdq2ps        xmm0, xmm1
        mulps   xmm0, xmm0
        paddd   xmm13, xmm8
        cvtdq2ps        xmm13, xmm13
        sub     eax, 1
        mulps   xmm13, xmm13
        addps   xmm14, xmm6
        mulps   xmm12, xmm12
        addps   xmm0, xmm5
        addps   xmm13, xmm4
        addps   xmm12, xmm3
        addps   xmm0, xmm14
        addps   xmm0, xmm13
        addps   xmm0, xmm12
        movdqa  xmm12, xmm1
        cvttps2dq       xmm0, xmm0
        paddd   xmm2, xmm0
        jne     .L2
        add     edx, 1
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm10
        cmp     edx, 1280
        jne     .L4
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm2
        psrldq  xmm0, 8
        paddd   xmm2, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm2
        psrldq  xmm0, 4
        paddd   xmm2, xmm0
        movd    eax, xmm2
        ret
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_calculations():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
.LC1:
        .long   4
        .long   4
        .long   4
        .long   4
.LC2:
        .long   1
        .long   1
        .long   1
        .long   1
.LC3:
        .long   2
        .long   2
        .long   2
        .long   2
.LC4:
        .long   3
        .long   3
        .long   3
        .long   3
```

Your SIMD code generates:

```
calculations():
        pxor    xmm5, xmm5
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     r8d, 1
        movabs  rdi, -4294967296
        cvtsi2ss        xmm5, eax
.L4:
        mov     r9d, r8d
        mov     esi, 1
        movd    edx, xmm5
        pxor    xmm5, xmm5
        pxor    xmm4, xmm4
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        cvtsi2ss        xmm5, r8d
        add     r8d, 1
        cvtsi2ss        xmm4, r8d
        and     rdx, rdi
        or      rdx, rcx
        pxor    xmm2, xmm2
        mov     edx, edx
        movd    ecx, xmm5
        sal     rcx, 32
        or      rdx, rcx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rdx
        movd    edx, xmm4
        pxor    xmm4, xmm4
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        and     rdx, rdi
        or      rdx, rcx
        lea     ecx, [r9+2]
        mov     edx, edx
        cvtsi2ss        xmm4, ecx
        movd    ecx, xmm4
        sal     rcx, 32
        or      rdx, rcx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-16], rdx
        movaps  xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        mulps   xmm4, xmm4
.L2:
        movd    edx, xmm2
        mov     r10d, esi
        pxor    xmm2, xmm2
        pxor    xmm7, xmm7
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-40]
        cvtsi2ss        xmm2, esi
        add     esi, 1
        and     rdx, rdi
        cvtsi2ss        xmm7, esi
        or      rdx, rcx
        mov     ecx, edx
        movd    r11d, xmm2
        movd    edx, xmm7
        sal     r11, 32
        or      rcx, r11
        pxor    xmm7, xmm7
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rcx
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-32]
        and     rdx, rdi
        or      rdx, rcx
        lea     ecx, [r10+2]
        mov     edx, edx
        cvtsi2ss        xmm7, ecx
        movd    ecx, xmm7
        sal     rcx, 32
        or      rdx, rcx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-32], rdx
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40]
        mulps   xmm0, xmm0
        addps   xmm0, xmm4
        movaps  xmm3, xmm0
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        shufps  xmm3, xmm0, 85
        addss   xmm1, xmm3
        movaps  xmm3, xmm0
        unpckhps        xmm3, xmm0
        shufps  xmm0, xmm0, 255
        addss   xmm1, xmm3
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        cvttss2si       edx, xmm0
        add     eax, edx
        cmp     r10d, 5120
        jne     .L2
        cmp     r9d, 5120
        jne     .L4
        rep ret
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_calculations():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Note that the compiler's version is using `cvtdq2ps`, `paddd`, `cvtdq2ps`, `mulps`, `addps`, and `cvttps2dq`. All of these are SIMD instructions. By combining them effectively, the compiler generates fast code.

In constrast, your code generates a lot of `add`, `and`, `cvtsi2ss`, `lea`, `mov`, `movd`, `or`, `pxor`, `sal`, which are not SIMD instructions.

I suspect the compiler does a better job of dealing with data type conversion and data rearrangement than you do, and that this allows it to arrange its math more effectively.

Comment: So compiler generates code that is already SIMD-optimized and injecting SSE intrinsics will not accelerate it more?

Comment: "It depends" would be a fair answer here. There are certainly cases where you can optimize performance by adding SIMD-operations yourself, however in many cases a modern compiler will do a brilliant job optimizing without your interference.

Comment: @SørenV.Poulsen OK. I am not very good at assembly, but [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vSYRST) looks like compiler translates:
`v_x = _mm_mul_ps(v_x, v_x);`  
into this 5 instructions:  
```movaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR v_x$[rsp]  
    mulps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR v_x$[rsp]  
    movaps XMMWORD PTR $T8[rsp], xmm0  
    movaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T8[rsp]  
    movaps XMMWORD PTR v_x$[rsp], xmm0```
Why so many moves between memory? Is it necessary? Or it is a bad optimization?

Comment: You have to consider that SIMD operations are enabled only by having special registers available within the processor. There is a cost associated with moving values in and out of those registers, and generally speaking, the longer data is kept within the registers, the better. To move data in/out of SSE registers just for a couple of multiplications is maybe not worth it. The compiler will do these considerations for you.

Comment: @user1554270: The compiler will add SIMD if you compile with `-O2` or `-O3` (maybe even `-O1`). Using `-march=native` will allow it to use even more SIMD.

Comment: @Richard: clang enables auto-vectorization at `-O2`, gcc only at `-O3`.  Anyway, it looks like the big problem is the OP's horizontal sum *inside* the inner-most loop, with `result_v += (int)(result[0] + result[1] + result[2] + result[3]);`.  That's probably what's causing all that scalar work.  (But when auto-vectorizing, the compiler I guess manages to sink that hsum out of the loop, with a packed convert and packed 32-bit integer add into a vector accumulator.  `cvttps2dq       xmm0, xmm0` and  `paddd xmm2,xmm0`)